# Changing other user's registry through batch files

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file

Is it possible to change other user `HKCU` registry from other admin account?

My workflow is:

1. Install software on admin account.
2. Installation creates user "CustomUser"
3. I need to set some registry keys for this user...

I am able to create registry keys in ProfileList through command:

```
%windir%\System32\runas.exe /profile /user:domain\%targetUser% logonui.exe
```

But this doesn't creates target key in `HKEY_USERS`

I also tried impersonation through C# described in : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/124981/A-Complete-Impersonation-Demo-in-C-NET

But this line throws an exception:  `Boolean loadSuccess = 
                                LoadUserProfile(tokenDuplicate, ref profileInfo);`

Ideal way for me is to change registry just in batch file.

Comment: Why can't you have your program create the keys the first time it runs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either determine the 'CustomUser' SID beforehand and access it through HKU path, parsing reg.exe /add commands directly to the profile.

EXAMPLE SID

```
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-818888881-78888889-18888888-1000
```

or mount the NTUSER.DAT and avoid the SID busiesss.

```
REG LOAD HKU\ZZZ "C:\Documents and Settings\CustomUser\NTUSER.DAT"
REG ADD HKU\ZZZ\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce /v newUserProfile /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "D:\setup.cmd" /f
REG UNLOAD HKU\ZZZ
```

EDIT, here is how to find your CustomUser SID from WMIC.

```
wmic useraccount where name='CustomUser' get sid
```

Comment: First option: Yeah, that was my first idea, but in HKEY_USERS is not that key. I read that in HKEY_USERS are users which are logged in. I will try second option. Thanks

Comment: not a problem, whichever works for you.  added some details on where to gather the sid, alternatively you could wrap a set /p for /f tokens and pass sid around as a variable.

Comment: That file won't even exist yet.  It is only created when the account is first logged in.

Comment: I use second option. First i am using PSExec to execute LogonUI.exe, which creates user profile, and then i load it using your solution. Everythings works great! Thanks!