# LocalSystem - write to registry through batch file

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file, registry

I have service running as LocalSystem. From this service i am running batch files.

Some batch files affect registry. I am using regedit to import reg files.

Problem is, that these registry are not changed. It looks like problem with LocalSystem account. If i run service from VS, everything works fine.

Do you have any solution for this? A tried to run batch file as other user, without success. I am also trying to change my batch file (e.g use psexec or something).

I am open to anything, which can help.

Thanks

Comment: What parts of the registry are you trying to modify? Have you granted write access to those keys? Is there a reason you cannot instead manipulate the registry from within your service, rather than calling out to a batch file?

Comment: I am modifying HKEY_CURRENT_USER. To the rights, system has full control over this. Yes, because this service is something like update service, so it does not know anything about batch files content.

Comment: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` is a *view* over the `HKEY_USERS\...` registry branch asociated to the current user, and this *view* depends on the account/user reading/writing the registry. To change the registry for a user from a service running as `LocalSystem`, you need to directly write to the adecuate `HKEY_USERS\...` branch.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing other user's registry through batch files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20661593/changing-other-users-registry-through-batch-files)

Comment: But what if this user is not in HKEY_USERS ? I also try to load NTUSER.DAT file and write to the user. When service is running under admin account, it works...when as LocalSystem, it does not work.