# Changing other user's registry who hasn't logged in

Tags: windows, registry

I'm working on an easy way to provision in windows 10 and I'd like to be able to login as an admin then modify a non-admin's `HKCU` keys so that when they first login the settings will be set. I think I can edit through the HKEY_USERS node in the registry, but this non-admin's node doesn't exist there until they login. Is there some way to force the creation of this node? Or someway to edit the `HKCU` keys I want to modify? I found I can run `Get-WmiObject win32_useraccount` and get the non-admin users SID if that helps. Thanks!

There's a related post [on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20661593/changing-other-users-registry-through-batch-files) where (from the comments)it looks like they got it working using PSExec and LogonUI.exe, but I can't find any documentation on using LogonUI force creation of a user's `HKCU` hive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is loading the default `ntuser.dat` file. Then when the user logs in they have the correct HKCU keys. It's not as targeted since it effects all users rather than just the one I want.
Example

```
REG LOAD HKU\ZZZ "C:\Users\Default\NTUSER.DAT"
REG ADD HKU\ZZZ\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell
REG ADD HKU\ZZZ\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell /V TabletMode /T REG_dWORD /D 1 /F
REG UNLOAD HKU\ZZZ
```

Comment: I believe in the registry editor this file is editable via `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT`